# 2 urns in one container

Tags: probability

There are 4 white and 6 red balls in the first urn, 3 white and 5 red balls in the second urn. All the balls from the first and second urns were put into one container. We need to find the probability at randomly choosing one white ball from the first urn.

What I did is: Event B is choosing white ball, event A is choosing from the first urn.  Pr(A∣B)=4/18:7/18=4/7

Am I right?

Comment: Using *conditional probability* here seems wrong. The probability is simply $\frac{4}{4+6+3+5}$.

Comment: The probability $P(A\mid B)$ here would make more sense as an answer if the question was written "*What is the probability that a randomly chosen ball came from the first urn* **given that it was white**."  For that question the answer would indeed be $4/7$.  However, nothing with the way you have written the question seems to suggest working with conditional probability.

Comment: So is it just about an intersection of 2 events? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a condition if you see the term "given that", and an intersection otherwise.

Comment: There can of course be other equivalent ways to write conditional probability statements, such as with "If-Then" clauses.  "*If the color of the ball was white, what is the probability that it came from the first urn*" for example would also refer to $P(A\mid B)$.  What it comes down to is understanding the meaning of the sentence... unfortunately it would be impossible to create a comprehensive list since there is so much freedom with language.  "When is it an intersection vs a conditional" is like asking "in a word problem when is it addition or division."  It should be clear from context...